# How to make more efficient code in model?

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4, model, refactoring, import-from-csv

Any idea to refactor the code of the method `self.import_data` ? It's a method which allow the application to save CSV file in database (with some restriction on the user email). It's supposed to run every day at noon so it has to be quick.
Currently its very long to run when I have a big CSV file. I wonder if there a way to make this code more efficient and win some time (or to avoiding the loop or make less request...). I don't really know what makes the process so long actually and how to correct it.

Here is my model :

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  validates :email,  uniqueness: true
  require 'csv'

  def is_former_email?(update_email)
    self.versions.each do |version|
      next if version.object.nil?
      return true if version.object.include?(update_email)
    end
  end

 def self.import_data
   filename = File.join Rails.root, '/vendor/people.csv'

   CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, col_sep: ',') do  |row|
     firstname, lastname, home_phone_number, mobile_phone_number, email, address = row

     person = Person.find_or_create_by(firstname: row["firstname"], lastname: row['lastname'], address: row['address'] )
     if person.is_former_email?(row['email']) == true
       puts "not allowed"
     else
       person.update_attributes({firstname: row['firstname'], lastname: row['lastname'], home_phone_number: row['home_phone_number'], mobile_phone_number: row['mobile_phone_number'], address: row['address'], email: row['email']})
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a little refactored your code, but for more efficiently I recommend to use gem [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) and optimize versions model for search previous emails.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

  FILE_NAME = File.join Rails.root, '/vendor/people.csv'

  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  has_paper_trail

  def self.import_data
    people = CSV.new(File.new(FILE_NAME), headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all).to_a.map(&:to_hash)
    versions_by_item_id = Version.where(item_type: 'Person').select('item_id, object').group_by(&:item_id)

    people.each do |person_params|
      person = Person.find_or_create_by(person_params.slice(:firstname, :lastname, :address))
      if versions_by_item_id[person.id] && versions_by_item_id[person.id].sum { |v| v.object.to_s }.include?(person_params[:email])
        puts 'not allowed'
      else
        person.update_attributes(person_params.slice(:home_phone_number, :mobile_phone_number, :email))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Daniil for this good refacto. I just have this error : 
 irb(main):001:0> Person.import_data NameError: uninitialized constant Person::Version from /home/ludy/inch-test/app/models/person.rb:12:in import_data.

However good `Version` is a table...

Comment: Orsay, can you try Version.last from console?
Also try rename Version on ::Version.where ...

Comment: Ok It's because I have to call `PaperTrail::Version.where...`. So now it's fixed, I get an other error... :

  PaperTrail::Version Load (0.4ms)  SELECT item_id, object FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."item_type" = ?  [["item_type", "Person"]]
  Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."firstname" = ? AND "people"."lastname" = ? AND "people"."address" = ? LIMIT 1  [["firstname", "Henri"], ["lastname", "Dupont"], ["address", "10 Rue La bruyère"]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Orsay, I fixed sum method.

Comment: Ok great, it works ! Thanks for your advices. I don't want to abuse but do you know how can I see how many time the request took ? I execute it in rails console.

Comment: I recommend install gem [progress_bar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar) and move this code to rake task, it will be clear.
https://gist.github.com/linadmax/ff37a5392bc4fcd045b36c89999bf51a

You can to execute (or add to cron) it from bash console 
`rake run import:people`